# How to integrate UISearchDisplayController with a bar button item iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Until now I'm only familiar with one practice of UISearchDisplayController that integrating it with UISearchBar put on tableView. I see some apps when clicking bar button item it triggers UISearchDisplayController instead of touch on searchBar. Does anyone has any idea how to do it?

Comment: A UISearchDisplayController of itself is not an interface item, so how do you know what you're seeing _is_ a UISearchDisplayController? What exactly _are_ you seeing?

Comment: Why is it not a an interface? It contains a search bar, a table view

Comment: I tried to call
    [self.searchDC setActive:YES animated:YES];
UISearchDisplayController was triggered as expected, but it did not show search bar.

Comment: A UIDisplayController doesn't "contain" a search bar. You use it coupled with a search bar. It does provide a table view, that's true; but then all we know is that you are seeing a table view, yes? You still haven't answered my question about what you're seeing.

Comment: I init it with a search bar using
_searchDC = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:_searchBar contentsController:self];

Comment: I'm not asking what you are doing. I'm asking what you see in these apps you are trying to imitate. You click a bar button and you say "it triggers UISearchDisplayController" - what do those words mean to you?

Comment: In normal case, when you touch search which integrated with  UISearchDisplayController on the screen, search bar animate to the top and keyboard to search will appear, right? I want the same effect but instead of having to touch on my search bar, I want to tap on a button.

Comment: And you can see that happening in certain apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a trick to do it by writing following code in 2 delegate methods of search bar

```
- (void)searchButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
   self.dictionaryTableView.tableHeaderView = _searchBar;
   [self.searchDC setActive:YES animated:YES];
   [self.searchDC.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self.searchDC setActive:NO animated:YES];
    self.dictionaryTableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
}
```

The problem is UISearchDisplayController will not appear even setActive called if its search bar is not part of the view. Therefore, when button is tapped, I set searchBar to tableViewHeader, and activate searchdisplaycontroller. Then when the search is finished I inactivate searchdisplaycontroller, and set nil tableViewHeader to ensure the search bar won't show on the screen.